# Is it possible to disable mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to configure mysql not to use subquery?
Such as select id from table where no=(select no from...)

If it is possible  how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you want that to be disabled?

Comment: I don't think so, and I can't imagine why you would want to. Subqueries are pretty basic to SQL, you wouldn't be able to do much without them.

Comment: Why do you want to do so and what do you mean by disabling subsquery?

Comment: Just set privileges to tables and allow SELECT etc only for wanted tables. Then there shouldn't be problems to allow running subqueries.

Comment: I asked this because some mysql version says(dont know exact version) it is syntax error to use query as select id from table where no=(select 1) . if I chang e (select 1) to (1) it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable subqueries.
What you can do is use joins instead of subqueries.
Using joins is faster and easier to maintain.

- [how to rewrite your queries using joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)
- [Visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: turns out the mysql version was low, thats whay the subquery was not working.